# Why direct child selector is propagating?

Tags: css, css-cascade

On the snippet, the 3rd `h2` should not be affected by the css, so why it is?

```css
.a > div { color: blue; text-align: center; }
```

```html
<div class="a">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <div>
        <h2>this shoud be center and blue</h2>
        <div>
            <h2>this should Not be center or blue</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because some CSS properties are [inheritable](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#inheriting):

> *Inheritance* propagates property values from parent elements to their children. The *inherited value* of a property on an element is the
>   computed value of the property on the element’s parent element. [...]
>
> Some properties are *inherited properties*, as defined in their
>   property definition table. This means that, unless the cascade results
>   in a value, the value will be determined by inheritance.

In this case, both `color` and `text-align` are inheritable. If you don't want that element to inherit those properties, you can provide some value in the cascading. For example, you can set these properties to their [initial value](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#initial-value), via the [`initial` keyword](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade-3/#initial):

```css
.a div { /* Set initial values to all descendants */
  color: initial;
  text-align: initial;
}
.a > div { /* Set desired values to children */
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <div>
    <h2>this shoud be center and blue</h2>
    <div>
      <h2>this should Not be center or blue</h2>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not propagating, the children of the `.a>div` are inheriting `styles` from their `parent`, since they don't have `color` and `text-align` set.

[image]

```css
.a > div {
  color: blue;
  text-align: center;
}
div {
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">

  <h2>London 1</h2>
  <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>

  <div class="">


    <h2>this shoud be center and blue</h2>
    <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>

    <div class="">
      <h2>this should Not be center or blue</h2>
      <p>London is the capital city of England. It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
    </div>


  </div>



</div>
```

Comment: So what's the use of `>` selector?

Comment: @Tom Brito check the snippet above